# Error : Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm currently working on my little databases project, but I have already encountered problems. I ave a two tables which generated scripts are posted underneath and now I'm trying  to write a procedure which will add a record first to smaller one and next to the second using to it ID from the first one. But I'm getting an error: 
"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."
in line which tries to add default values to the table Klienci. 
I have no idea whats going on because there is no column or arguments so there should be no problem, at least like this one.

First table :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni](
    [IDKlientaIndywidualnego] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IDKlienta] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Imie] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Nazwisko] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [NumerLegitymacji] [int] NULL,
    [Adres] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Miasto] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [KodPocztowy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Kraj] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Telefon] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_KlienciIndywidualni] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDKlientaIndywidualnego] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_KlienciIndywidualni_Klienci] FOREIGN KEY([IDKlienta])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Klienci] ([IDKlienta])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_KlienciIndywidualni_Klienci]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_KlienciIndywidualni] CHECK  ((len([Telefon])>=(9)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_KlienciIndywidualni]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_KlienciIndywidualni_mail] CHECK  (([Email] like '%@%.[a-z][a-z][a-z]'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_KlienciIndywidualni_mail]
GO
```

Second one:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Klienci](
    [IDKlienta] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Klienci] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDKlienta] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dodaj_klienta_indywidualnego 
-- parametry
@Imie nvarchar(50),
@Nazwisko nvarchar(50),
@Adres nvarchar(50),
@KodPocztowy nvarchar(50),
@Miasto nvarchar(50) ,
@Kraj nvarchar(50),
@Telefon int,
@Email nvarchar(50),
@NumerLegitymacji nvarchar(50) = null

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @IDKlienta as int;

begin try
    begin tran
    --dodaj klienta
    INSERT INTO Klienci
    DEFAULT VALUES
    set @IDKlienta = @@IDENTITY;

    --dodaj klienta indywidualnego
    INSERT INTO KlienciIndywidualni
    VALUES(@IDKlienta, @Imie, @Nazwisko, @Adres, @Miasto, 
    @KodPocztowy, @Kraj, @Telefon, @Email);
    COMMIT TRAN
end try
begin catch
    declare @error as varchar(127)
    set @error = (Select ERROR_MESSAGE())
    RAISERROR('Nie mozna dodac osoby-klienta, blad danych. %s', 16, 1, @error);
    ROLLBACK TRAN
end catch
END
GO
```

Comment: The error is `INSERT INTO KlienciIndywidualni` not the line you think. You have missed out `NumerLegitymacji`. Add a parameter for it - or if you don't want to insert anything into that column use an explicit column list that excludes that column.

Comment: Why have a table that ONLY has an identity field?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second insertion needs ten parameters, you only provided 9, if you will skip the `NumerLegitymacji` field then you should specify each column by its name, cause the insertion now awaits the last NOT NULL column.

```
    --dodaj klienta indywidualnego
    INSERT INTO KlienciIndywidualni (
    IDKlienta,
    Imie,
    Nazwisko,
    Adres,
    Miasto,
    KodPocztowy,
    Kraj,
    Telefon,
    Email
)
    VALUES(@IDKlienta, @Imie, @Nazwisko, @Adres, @Miasto, 
    @KodPocztowy, @Kraj, @Telefon, @Email);
    COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: `NumerLegitymacji` does actually allow `NULL` but that is irrelevant. If no column list is included values must be supplied for all columns except computed/identity ones.

Comment: Spent like 2 hours working on that problem and I didn't even suppose there answer is so simple. This line in error just made me just watching on first table insert. Thanks for help guys. Now it's working fine.

Comment: If I got you right, then he should write the fields that will be assigned a value as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @MuhammadHani - Yes. I was just pointing out the phrasing "awaits the last NOT NULL column." is somewhat incorrect.

Comment: @MuhammadHani Wanted to mark it earlier but i just had to wait 5 min because of site. ;p