# SQL Server trigger for cascade insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

I have 2 tables I'm working with:

- WPCMA69_Connector
- WPCMA70_ConnectorPocket

Since the relationship properties has an "update" and "delete" Cascade , I'm developing a trigger to handle insert.  ConnectorName is the field in common that I want to automatically insert from the PCMA69 table to the PCMA70 table after an insert command on PCMA69.

- PCMA69_ConnectorName_N

  - (PK,nvarchar(50,not null)
- PCMA70_ConnectorName_N

  - (FK,nvarchar(50),not null)

This is what I've tried:

```
alter trigger trigConnector
ON dbo.WPCMA69_Connector
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @ConnectorName nvarchar(50)

   SELECT @Connectorname = PCMA69_ConnectorName_N 
   FROM inserted

   INSERT INTO WPCMA70_ConnectorPocket 
   VALUES (@ConnectorName)
END
```

However, I get the error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trigConnector, Line 9
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Your error is because you didn't specify the columns for your insert. Your trigger however has a MAJOR flaw. You are using scalar variables which indicates it can't handle multiple row operations. You need to create set based queries in your triggers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408922/error-column-name-or-number-of-supplied-values-does-not-match-table-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something along these lines.

```
insert into WPCMA70_ConnectorPocket (WhateverYourColumnIsHere) 
Select PCMA69_ConnectorName_N from inserted
```

If you have more than 1 row in an operation it will only pick up one of those rows when you have scalar variables involved.

Comment: Thank you.  I have another question along the same lines which I don't think requires a seperate question.  If I'm inserting into a table with columns that can't be null, that's not involved in the insert statement, how can I solve that?

Comment: You can't. When a column has NOT NULL constraint you MUST provide a value for that column period. There is no work around. That is the point of a not null constraint.

Comment: Ok.  That makes sense.  I was just curious if there was a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into WPCMA70_ConnectorPocket (PCMA70_ConnectorName_N) 
values (@ConnectorName)
```

Comment: This fixes the issue but the underlying logic flaw of scalar triggers is still present.